# Change Fastlane execution folder while inside a lane

Tags: ruby, fastlane

We have a flow where we execute a custom script which copies the project on the desktop before it is signed and submitted.

Now we want to use Fastlane and we were thinking to do the following:

1. We start the `fastlane build` process
2. We execute the custom `sh` script
3. We do all the `fastlane` magic

And I am thinking the following - since my sh script is copying the project on the desktop, how can I continue the `fastlane` script execution from the copied folder and not the original (source) folder?

Should we start `fastlane` from our custom script instead?

Comment: Could you add a bit more information _why_ you copy the project to the desktop? And what work you still want to do on that project on the desktop?

Comment: @janpio, we execute some custom actions like replacing images, translations, etc., because we create white-label apps. That's why we copy the original project to the desktop and copy some additional files there.

Comment: Wouldn't that work as well in a `build` folder inside the project? (Maybe subfolder for the customer and the version there) Then this could be handled a lot easier in your `Fastfile` with a simple `Dir.chdir` (although directory handling in fastlane still is a bit tricky as it switches between the `Fastfile` and the project path depending on what you execute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think fastlane is designed to change its working directory while running. It sets up a ton of environment variables when running and if any of those point to the old location you might be in trouble.

Make two fastlane lanes, one for the old location, one for the new. Then your script looks like this

```
cd old-location
fastlane old_lane
cp -r old-location new-location
cd new-location
fastlane new_lane
```

Fastlane is great... for certain tasks. Personally I've had a lot more success treating it as a convenience wrapper for a few specific functions rather than an all-in-one solution, so don't be afraid to break out of it. For example, we only use fastlane for submitting our app, not for building and testing ([read more](https://silverhammermba.github.io/blog/2019/03/12/slowlane)).